# What is the best container for html5-videos?

Tags: html5-video, blender

I have some videos I try to convert with Blender into a format which could be rendered by the most modern Browsers. I tried many different Settings and neither IE nor Firefox was able to decode the files. (Windows Media Player always did.)

I use the following html code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="data/test.avi">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Is this correct?

I tried different formats, codecs and reslolutions. (mpeg-4, h.264, ogg, theora).

Do you have any suggestions?

Edit:
Ogg-Theora does run in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE.

Answer (score 1):

This is and has always been an issue, that is, format "wars" - which format to use, both for audio and video.

Unfortunately (depending on what angle you look at it) there is not one single format to rule them all, so you actually have to provide as many as "possible". By possible at least the three main formats:

- MP4
- Ogg Video
- WebM

You can choose priority by defining the source tag in the order you prefer them to be used:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="data/test.mp4"  type="video/mpeg" />
    <source src="data/test.ogv"  type="video/ogg"  />
    <source src="data/test.webm" type="video/webm" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Hope this gives some input.

Comment: Some tests told me that if a browser supports one format also depends on the bitrate and length of the Video. This is so frustrating.

Comment: @Matthias it is.. and very little we can do about it unfortunately (though length of file should not matter).

Comment: Shouldn't it state "video/mp4" instead of "video/mpeg" ? see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp